# MS VC++ Compiler Bug - Fixed Size C-String Curly Brace Initializer

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am having trouble with fixed-size c-string initialization using curly brackets in Microsoft VC++. This doesn't happen in GCC or clang. It appears that the initialization of each struct is not being performed correctly relative to each array element's address. Is this potentially a MS bug, and if so, how might I work around it while still maintaining fixed size c-strings with same-sized and smaller string constants?

This can be seen on:

- Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2): 14.0.25123.00
- Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3): 14.0.25431.01
- https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual (19.00.23506)

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct StringTableEntry_t
{
    static constexpr size_t MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 8;

    const char String[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];  
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr size_t STRING_TABLE_ENTRY_COUNT = 4;

    static constexpr StringTableEntry_t STRING_TABLE[STRING_TABLE_ENTRY_COUNT] =
    {
        { "THESE" },
        { "ARE" },
        { "TEST" },
        { "VALUES" }
    };

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < STRING_TABLE_ENTRY_COUNT; ++idx)
    {
        printf("idx=%zu: %s\n", idx, STRING_TABLE[idx].String);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output on VC++:

```
idx=0: THESE
idx=1: E
idx=2: ALUES
idx=3:
```

Output on GCC/clang:

```
idx=0: THESE
idx=1: ARE
idx=2: TEST
idx=3: VALUES
```

Comment: What version of Visual C++ are you using?

Comment: Updated to include VC++ versions

Comment: There is no issue with Visual Studio 2019.  Also, you should be using Update 3 if you're using 2015.

Comment: works for me in 2017 too

Comment: Pasting your code into the online compiler you linked and enabling warnings shows this 'strange' library path: `/LIBPATH:C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib`. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @AdrianMole I also see this on VS 2015 Updates 2 and 3. I will try on VS 2017, but I don't believe I can update anytime soon - any possible workaround?

Comment: Like the others who have commented, I can't reproduce your error on VS2019. Only on the website you linked.

Comment: The workaround is to not use `constexpr`.  You're using a compiler that is two major versions behind the latest version.

Comment: It does not appear to happen on VS 2017 (15.7.3). Updated the question.

Comment: Works in 2017 / 2019 versions. 
Do you think this could be a problem with `boost_1_60_0\stage\lib` ?

Comment: My Visual Studio 2015 doesn't use boost. But removing the constexpr works - must be a bug that was resolved in 2017+.